# Can i add extension in my id after using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new in PHP I have recently changed my URL
from

```
www.example.com/page.php?id=1
```

to

```
www.example.com/1
```

by using this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

but I want to add .html extension after id like this

```
www.example.com/1.html
```

I don't have more knowledge about URL rewrite
help me, please.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Because you have this optional slash in the beginning of the rule, I can access `example.com/1` and `example.com//1`. Do you need those double slashes? If not, consider changing the rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier, and more stable,way now unless you are using a very old version of Apache.

```
FallbackResource /test.php
```

And then parse the PATHINFO:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: This solution normally requires some additional work. It is not a drop in replacement for the mod_rewrite solution. And forgive me for the obvious comment, but "not working" tells us nothing useful.